# improving user preferences based on behavior

Tags: recommender-system

I have a project to improve user experience in our software by gathering data on their actions while using the software and comparing that to preferences they made when initializing the software. The idea is that if they say they like Coke but they keep drinking Pepsi, we would (1) ask "Are you sure you like Coke, not Pepsi?", (2) just change their user settings to Pepsi, or (3) incorporate their usage history into whatever logic already uses their initialization preferences. Not all user preferences are exclusively categorical. Some may be continuous (30% Coke 70% Pepsi). Now, I could probably solve this programmatically but it seems like a statistical or machine learning approach might be better.

Can someone tell me if this is a particular class of problem and/or point me to any literature that attempts to solve this from a statistical (or ML) point of view?

Comment: Your question is well-phrased and interesting, although I'd challenge the implication of a distinction between a *programatic solution* versus a *statistical or machine learning* solution". Any machine learning or stats based approach will be in the form of a program.

Comment: That is true. I am sure I lack the vocabulary to properly make the distinction, but perhaps I can clarify. By programmatic I meant not-derived-by-statistical-model.